# Instagram 30 # Limit - Can't Delete Comments Containing 30th Hashtag

Tags: instagram

Instagram has a 30-hashtag limit for every post. In the latest release (version 5.0.2) once you post a comment with the 30th hashtag, you cannot remove that comment.

From smartphone or desktop, after clicking the trash can icon as you normally would, the comment containing the 30th hashtag will disappear as if it were deleted, however, upon refreshing the page, the comment will return. Any other non-hashtag comments made thereafter will post and delete as normal...

Any one experience this? Anyone have a solution?

Thanks for your help,
@nperspectiv

Instagram help only has this one article: http://help.instagram.com/249533351836449